# What are the current limitations/risks of Ionic React in comparison to Ionic Angular?

Tags: angular, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am a ReactJS developer and I'm going to be starting my first Ionic project soon. I really want to use Ionic React, but it's currently in early beta. I understand the inherent risk of unknown issues cropping up, but I am having a hard time figuring out what the *known* limitations or issues are with Ionic React (as compared to Ionic Angular)?

I've never used Ionic Angular before so looking at the [**Ionic React documentation**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/react), it seems to be in a very usable state. I also checked the GitHub issues and there doesn't seem to be that many related to React specifically.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The biggest caveat of Angular-Ionic when you are a ReactJS developer is Angular :) It's quite big framework to learn and it's much faster to work with what you already know. Have you considered React Native?

Comment: have you checked NativeScript?

Comment: We need to have a web, desktop, and mobile app for our product, and we don't have the development capacity to build them separately. Ionic seems more efficient than React Native and NativeScript in that way.

Comment: I would say it mostly depends on your App's requirement, if you need to use a lot of plugins, you might get in trouble with ionic-react.

Otherwise it seems to work perfectly. We just finished building an app with builds for web, mobile-web, iOS and android

Comment: We actually went with Ionic-React but decided that we will be migrating off of it. It was supposed to get compatibility with IE after beta but they decided not to, nor does it work with non-Chromium-Edge, both of which are important to us (~20% of users). It's also a difficult UI framework to customize, it uses very modern browser APIs that aren't always supported by browsers or external tools (e.g. FullStory/LogRocket), and Capacitor alone is enough to let us deploy the app without using the Ionic framework itself.